# how to get the closest element from a selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get closest anchor tag while i'm selecting the text `3 This is`from the below html.

So i want to get the closest anchor tag id to it.

so i want to get the anchor tag with id `a_3` or span with tag with id `sp_3`

```
<a id="a_1"></a><span id="sp_1">1</span><value>This is the text 1</value>
<a id="a_2"></a><span id="sp_2">2</span><value>This is the text 2</value>
<a id="a_3"></a><span id="sp_3">3</span><value>This is the text 3</value>
<a id="a_4"></a><span id="sp_4">4</span><value>This is the text 4</value>

var anchorTag = $('#sp_3').closest("A");
```

Expected the output of this is 
       `<a id="a_3"></a>` 
but it returned

```
init [prevObject: init(1), context: undefined]
```

please help me

Comment: is this a select dropdown

Comment: Just FYI, there's no `<value />` element in HTML

Answer (score 1):

use `prev`. `span` is not nested within the `anchor`, it is a sibling. So, `closest` will not work. `closest` start searching for `selector` on element itself and traversing up through it's ancestors.

`var anchorTag = $('#sp_3').prev('a');`

```js
var anchorTag = $('#sp_3').prev('a');
console.log(anchorTag[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="a_1"></a><span id="sp_1">1</span>
<value>This is the text 1</value>
<a id="a_2"></a><span id="sp_2">2</span>
<value>This is the text 2</value>
<a id="a_3"></a><span id="sp_3">3</span>
<value>This is the text 3</value>
<a id="a_4"></a><span id="sp_4">4</span>
<value>This is the text 4</value>
```

Comment: I deleted mine because you added the [0], and yours is more informative.

Comment: @Noam - That's Okay. We all are here to learn, help and improve :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the click event on the specific element you are clicking on.
Try to relate it with your question may be it helps. :)

```js
$("#myid").on("click",function(){
alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="myid"><span id="spanID">click here</span></a>
```